# Dropdown menu linguagem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Visualizei em um site que existe no canto superior direito um menu dropdown onde o usuário pode fazer a seleção da língua. Abaixo um print do site com a opção de seleção aberta. Quando o usuário clicar em Français, por exemplo, a bandeira da França aparece no lugar da bandeira do Brasil. Gostaria de saber como fazer isso usando javascript/jquery! Procurei e não achei nenhum código.

[image: menu imagem]

Comment: Especifique mais pois existem varias maneiras de se fazer, com JS pode trocar o src da imagem com a bandeira do brasil,  colocando o src da imagem que voce quer. Poderia tambem quando clicar redirecionar para a mesma pagina com o idioma diferente meu/site/index.php?lang=fr, e coloca a bandeira de acordo com o idioma via php.

Comment: em javascript/jquery de preferencia. se tu tiver algo mande

Comment: ta usando algum framework css? bootstrap, foundation?

Comment: usando bootstrap

Comment: Você já possui algo? Quer somente o `dropdown` com as imagens ou fazer a tradução do site também?

Comment: traducao ja fiz usando cookies, session e um arquivo php para cada traducao usando array! a url fica tipo isso: index.php?lang=br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como não consegui fazer o tooltip funcionar, não coloquei estilo, mas o básico que você pediu acho que é isso:

```js
//a estrutura e como esse objeto vai ser populado você decide como vai ser, aqui foi só exemplo
var langList = [
 {name: 'Portugues', code:'pt-BR', icon:'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/world-flag-icons/256/Flag_of_Brazil.png'},
 {name: 'Ingles', code:'en-US', icon:'http://icons.veryicon.com/png/Flag/Rounded%20World%20Flags/United%20States%20Flag.png'},
]

$(document).ready(function(){
 $langs = $('#langs');
    $currentLang = $('#current-lang');
    var lang;
    //aqui é so para popular a lista, ela poderia vir do servidro ja populada tambem
    for( var i in langList){
        lang = langList[i];
     $langs.append('<li data-index="'+i+'" class="lang-picker"><img src="'+lang.icon+'" width="50" /> '+lang.name+'</li>');
    }
    
    $('.lang-picker').on('click', function(){
     var index = $(this).attr('data-index');
        var lang = langList[index];
        if(lang){
         $currentLang.attr('src', lang.icon);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Por algum motivo que desconheco o tooltip da bootstrap nao funcionou aqui, mas o conceito é o mesmo -->
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/world-flag-icons/256/Flag_of_Brazil.png" width="50" id="current-lang" />
<br />

Idiomas diponiveis<br>
<ul id="langs">
</ul>
```

Comment: vou testar!!!!!!

Comment: é isso mesmo que estava precisando! vc é o kra neuber

Comment: se te ajudou nao esquece do +1 na resposta ;)

Comment: certo, mas acho q minha reputacao ainda esta baixa para isso